# SCOPE_IDENTITY, @@IDENTITY and IDENT_CURRENT return null

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

dbo, full permissions, local SQL Server Express database, tables I created and own.

I have just INSERTed a row into `MLA` and if I do a `SELECT * FROM MLA` I get the row I just inserted...

```
19 2019-04-16 15:02:52.000 Test
```

The "19" is the key, which is an identity column. So I try to get that key with any of these...

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MLA')
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

And they all return NULL.

The row was inserted with this line of code:

```
DbS.Execute(SQL)
```

where DbS is an active, working connection to the server which was also used for the insert. I then attempt to retrieve the key with this code:

```
Dim DT as RecordSet
DT = DbS.Open("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('USAA_ArgusVal_MLA')")
```

I can imagine that the Open makes a new scope, that would not explain `@@IDENTITY`

**UPDATE**: here is the solution that was suggested below, I simply added the `SELECT` to the existing `INSERT` SQL statement, and changed the `.Execute` to using this code

```
SQL &= vbCrLf & "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS MLAKey"
Dim DI As RecordSet = DbS.Open(SQL)
If DI.Read Then
    MLAKey = DI!MLAKey
Else
    MLAKey = ""
End If
```

Comment: what is the type of Dbs. Presumably a new connection is being opened for each execution.

Comment: The DBS is the SQLNativeClient (11 IIRC).

Comment: What is the underlying .NET datatype? Doesnt look like `SqlConnection` for example as that doesnt have an open method executing a query string

Comment: Yes, sorry, Execute is simply a cover for a DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery. Which I assume is also it's own scope.

Comment: Why use ADODB Recordset objects in .NET? I'd suggest to convert to SqlClient DataTable objects, for starters. Also, I prefer to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY() as an output parameter back to the calling code. This way, if I wanted to re-select the inserted data to refresh the screen for the user (visual confirmation that the data was successfully saved), I can do that AND have the new identity returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "dbs" connection probably has some connection pooling.

Write SQL INSERT and then SELECT identity in the same SQL statement.
Best solution is to create a stored procedure to insert data and then return current identity.

Comment: I normally use ExecuteNonQuery for INSERT, can I do an insert in a dbs.Open(...)? I've never actually used that method before.

Comment: To be pedantic, I think you meant `output`, not `return`.

Comment: This solution works. I will edit the question to show what I did.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz No, please don't edit the solution into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `OUPTUT` clause and perform insert + select as single operation:

```
INSERT INTO MLA(...)
OUTPUT inserted.identity_column_name
VALUES(...)
```